# truncate string when try to Insert string to MySQL by C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I wrote stored procedure in MySql and try to call it with C# and MySql.Data.MySqlClient  to insert data to database but the strings are truncated.

the Code I use in C# is:

```
    public long InsertDataToMain(int aboutType, string pageTitle, string pageText, ImageProperty imgProp)
    {
        long ArticleNumber = 0;
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            var myConnection =
                new MySqlConnection("server=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;uid=XXXXXXXX;port=3306;pwd=XXXXXXXX;database=wikitest;charset=utf8");

            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Routine_Transfer_Wiki_Data")
            {
                Connection = myConnection,
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            MySqlParameter paramPageType = new MySqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "param_page_type_id",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int16,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = aboutType
            };

            MySqlParameter paramPageTitle = new MySqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "param_page_title",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
                Size = 255,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageTitle.Replace(" ","_")))
            };
            MySqlParameter paramPageLen = new MySqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "param_page_len",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int64,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageText).Length
            };

            MySqlParameter paramPageText = new MySqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "param_old_text",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.MediumBlob,
                //Size = 16777215,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageText))
            };
            myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
            {
                paramPageType, 
                paramPageTitle, 
                paramPageLen, 
                paramPageText,
            });

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }

       }
```

so, when the method is execute the paramPageText content is truncated.

Comment: What's the field type in the database, and how long is the text? Why are you storing text in a blob anyway? That doesn't sound like a good idea - nor do the multiple encoding conversions you're performing. (I'd also strongly recommend `using` statements instead of try/finally...)

Comment: 1- DB Field is Blob 
2- The text Size is around 6000 character
3- I try to insert to insert data to WikiMedia DB, so I can't Modify the Database Design
4- I agree with u but i use Multiple text converting to be ensure the final text is UTF-8
5- Thanx for your Suggest about using Using 

Comment: Just "blob" with no limits? (All of this should be in the question - and ideally you should cut down your code to *just* what is required to demonstrate the problem. Given that it's a blob, why bring strings into it at all? You should be able to show the truncation with a simple byte array.)

Comment: 3- I try to insert data to WikiMedia DB, so I can't Modify the Database Design

Comment: "I agree with u but i use Multiple text converting to be ensure the final text is UTF-8 " - you're setting the value to be a *string* despite it being a blob field, and you're converting the same text to bytes in the same way multiple times. You really, really don't need to do that. Just convert it once and use that byte array for both the value and the length. Currently you're relying on however the driver decides to convert strings to binary for blobs.

Comment: Tahnx for your explain but the main problem still remain

Comment: Then again, I suggest you display that with a short but complete program demonstrating *just* the problem, without any strings at all. You're inserting into a blob field, so if that's getting truncated you should be able to demonstrate that without any text being involved.